# time to destination on google assistant sdk using raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am working on Google Assistant SDK on raspberry pi 3. Is there any way to get the functionality of "time to a certain destination?". I'm getting a blank response when I ask this question.

Comment: I just asked "How long will it take to get to starbucks" and it gave me a few locations

Comment: What file did you use? I was using textinput.py.

Comment: I sent an audio query

Comment: Is it possible to send a text input for such queries?  I tried using text input and it dint work

Comment: It's translated to text before being processed, so I don't believe the issue is related to the input type.